# ¿Cómo hago para calcular el área de un polígono conociendo sus coordenadas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, funciones

Quiero calcular el área de cualquier polígono ingresando sus coordenadas, hice la función para calcular el área según la fórmula que está en la imagen y al correr el programa el valor del área me sale incorrecto.

[image]

Punto 1:

```
n=int(input("Ingrese el número de lados del polígono:"))

x=[]

y=[]

vértices=[]

for i in range(n):
    coordenada_x=int(input("Ingrese el valor de la coordenada x"+str(i)+":"))
    coordenada_y=int(input("Ingrese el valor de la coordenada y"+str(i)+":"))
    x.append(coordenada_x)
    y.append(coordenada_y)
    vértices.append(coordenada_x,coordenada_y)

x.append(x[0])
y.append(y[0])
```

Punto 2:

```
from entrada import n
from entrada import x,y

for i in range(n):
  Suma=(x[i]*(y[i+1]-y[i-1]))

Área_Polígono=(1/2)*abs(Suma)

print("Área del polígono=:",Área_Polígono,"U^2")
```

Al correr el programa:

```
Ingrese el número de lados del polígono:3
Ingrese el valor de la coordenada x0:0
Ingrese el valor de la coordenada y0:0
Ingrese el valor de la coordenada x1:1
Ingrese el valor de la coordenada y1:0
Ingrese el valor de la coordenada x2:1
Ingrese el valor de la coordenada y2:1
Coordenadas_x=[0,1,1,0]
Coordenadas_y=[0,0,1,0]
Vértices=[(0,0),(1,0),(1,1)]
```

El error ocurre con el área, ya que me aparece lo siguiente:

```
Área del polígono=0.0 U^2
```

Cuando el área en este caso debería ser 0.5 U^2

Comment: Agrega lo que lleves por favor

Comment: @jfmejiat el código que has mostrado no muestra tu intento ya que la lectura de datos es trivial. Muestra un intento real.

Comment: @jfmejiat No quiero suponer nada. Muestra lo que se te ha pedido si deseas ayuda. Practicamente estas pidiendo: "Haz mi tarea"

Comment: @jfmejiat no tienes que enviar nada, solo edita tu pregunta. Te recomiendo leer [ask] y pasar el [tour]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en:

```
x.append([coordenada_x,x[0]])
y.append([coordenada_y,y[0]])
```

esto lo que hace es crear una nueva lista mediante un literal:

```
x.append([coordenada_x, x[0]])
         ^                  ^
         ^                  ^
```

que contiene como primer elemento la última coordenada agregada en el `for`:

```
x.append([coordenada_x, x[0]])
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

y como segundo la primera coordenada (índice 0 de la lista):

```
x.append([coordenada_x, x[0]])
                        ^^^^
                        ^^^^
```

y esa nueva lista la agrega al final de la lista que ya tenias como un nuevo item, en tu caso:

```
coordenadas_x -> [0, 1, 2, [0, 2]]
coordenadas_y -> [0, 1, 2, [0, 2]]
```

En realidad te has complicado mucho sin necesidad, simplemente necesitas hacer:

```
x.append(x[0])
y.append(y[0])
```

Se asume que la lista tiene al menos un elemento, en realidad debe tener al menos 3 por la propia definición de polígono, lo cual puedes considerar validar por si el usuario ingresara `n < 3`.

```
n = int(input("Ingrese el número de vértices del polígono: "))

x = []
y = []

for i in range(n):
    coordenada_x = int(input(f"Ingrese el valor de la coordenada x{i}: "))
    coordenada_y = int(input(f"Ingrese el valor de la coordenada y{i}: "))
    x.append(coordenada_x)
    y.append(coordenada_y)

x.append(x[0])
y.append(y[0])

print("coordenadas_x=", x)
print("coordenadas_y=", y)
```

Para iterar agrupando los pares <kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>y</kbd> de cada coordenada puedes:

- Lo mejor es usar el builtin `zip`:

  ```
  for cord_x, cord_y in zip(x, y):
      print(f"Coordenada X: {cord_x}; Coordenada Y: {cord_y}")
  ```
- `for in` + `enumerate` + indizado:

  ```
  for ind, cord_x in enumerate(x):
      cord_y = y[ind]
      print(f"Coordenada X: {cord_x}; Coordenada Y: {cord_y}")
  ```
- Indizando con `for` y `range` (la menos eficiente y pitónica):

  ```
  for ind in range(len(x)):
      cord_x = x[ind]
      cord_y = y[ind]
      print(f"Coordenada X: {cord_x}; Coordenada Y: {cord_y}")
  ```

O si quieres una nueva lista con las parejas de coordenadas por vértice:

```
vertices = list(zip(x, y))
print(vertices)
```

> [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (0, 0)]

o generar la lista directamente en el `for`:

```
x = []
y = []
vertices = []

for i in range(n):
    coordenada_x = int(input(f"Ingrese el valor de la coordenada x{i}: "))
    coordenada_y = int(input(f"Ingrese el valor de la coordenada y{i}: "))
    x.append(coordenada_x)
    y.append(coordenada_y)
    vertices.append((x, y))
```

En ambos casos iteraría igual:

```
for cord_x, cord_y in vertices:
    print(f"Coordenada X: {cord_x}; Coordenada Y: {cord_y}")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: @jfmejiat Marca esta respuesta como aceptada si solucionó tu problema, para ayudar a la gente que tenga el mismo problema en un futuro :D